# Functional Programming: is foldLeft is the parent method of all functional methods such as foldRight, map, filter

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm learning Scala and a new comer in Functional Programming world. I see that most of all methods such as `foldRight`, `map`, `filter`, `reduce` ... always can be written by `foldLeft` (written foldRight by foldLeft for using tails recursion).

For example:

```
def map[A, B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] =
    foldRight(l, Nil: List[B])((x, xs) => Cons(f(x), xs))

def reverse[A](l: List[A]): List[A] =
    foldLeft(l, l)((xs, x) => Cons(x, xs))

def foldRight[A, B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B =
    foldLeft(reverse(l), z)((xs, x) => f(x, xs))
```

Before I come to functional programming world, I think that `map` and `reduce` is two basic methods of functional programming. From these two methods, I can build more complicated methods. But based on above example, I think `foldLeft` should be base all functional methods such as map, filter, ...

Is that true in functional programming world ?

Thanks

Comment: In some sense, you're right, up to isomorphism. You might be interested in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.698.4485) (and similar ones), which takes the idea of "ancestors of functions over a data type" a bit further.

Comment: If I recall correct it's foldRight that plays the important role, not foldLeft. In fact `list.foldRight(empty)(_ :: _) == list` and `list.foldLeft(empty)(_ flip(::) _) == list.reverse`, flip being a function that switches the order of arguments of a binary function.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no, `foldLeft` is not the "father" of all other methods, because there are many collections other than `List`. For example, you can not implement `Stream.map` via `Stream.foldLeft` because `foldLeft` does a full traversal but `map` should not traverse the stream because of its laziness (it can be potentially infinite).

As to the `List` you are mostly right. However, some methods will be extremely inefficient if implemented via `foldLeft`. Consider `list.drop(1)`. It should just return the tail of the list, but `foldLeft` would do a full traversal.

Comment: But while map certainly is not in any way a child of foldLeft (because it has, fundamentally, the wrong signature), nevertheless, foldLeft could be considered the "father" of the aggregation methods such as reduce.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to expand my comment into an answer.

Let's start with a type called *Bunch[T]* which is *Traversable[T]*, the base trait for all Scala collections. It implements all the usual monadic stuff like *map[U](f: T=>U)*, etc.

Let's now begin to classify all of the methods according to their signature. In the following, *U* is a supertype of *T*:

- *traversing*: there are actually two subclasses:

  - *shape-preserving*: these define a return type of *Bunch[U]*; example: *map*;
  - *non-shape-preserving*: these define a return type of *Iterator[T]*, *Traversable[T]*, *Traversable[U]*, etc.; example: *iterator*;
- *selecting*: these define a return type of *T*; example *head*;
- *maybeSelecting*: these define a return type of *Option[U]*
- *aggregation*: these define a return type of *U*; example: *foldLeft*;
- *testing*: these define a return type of *Boolean*; example: *empty*;
- *side-effecting*: these define a return type of *Unit*; example *foreach*;
- etc. etc.

Each of these classes of method is fundamentally different from the others. Some, such as aggregation, require a full traversal of the collection (which would not be possible on a *Stream*, for instance). Others do not.

We could possibly define a "father" method for each of these classes of method. For example, the father method for the class I called "side-effecting" would obviously be *foreach*. I think it might be reasonable to call *foldLeft* the "father" of the "aggregating" methods. But I think that, in general, we are bound to run into problems with this approach. You can't always define one method in terms of one other. *map* itself can be defined in terms of others methods, but it requires two: *flatMap* and "unit", a constructor method and therefore not in my list.

Answer (score 1):

In some sense you are right. In his 1999 paper [*A tutorial on the expressiveness and universality of fold*](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf), Graham Hutton reviews how to use `fold` for proving stuff without using recursion and for defining recursive functions, in order to show how expressive this function is.